# "No module named lxml" on AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, module, lxml

I'm trying to run my discordbot.py file on the Amazon EC2 server using MobaXTerm

I've tried every type of installion like:

```
sudo yum install python-lxml
sudo yum install libxml2-devel libxslt-devel python-devel
sudo yuminstall libxml2-dev libxslt-dev python-dev
pip install lxml
etc.
```

It always tells me stuff like:

```
Package python-lxml-3.2.1-4.amzn2.0.2.x86_64 already installed and latest version

Package gcc-7.3.1-12.amzn2.x86_64 already installed and latest version

Package libxml2-devel-2.9.1-6.amzn2.5.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version

Package libxslt-devel-1.1.28-6.amzn2.x86_64 already installed and latest version

Package python-devel-2.7.18-1.amzn2.0.3.x86_64 already installed and latest version

Nothing to do
```

Yet when I want to run my discord bot, it gives me:

```
     import lxml.html
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named lxml
```

I don't know what to do from that point on.

Comment: Try `pip3 install lxml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The solution was to use `pip3 install lxml`, rather then `pip install lxml`. The reason is that the former command uses Python 2, not **Python 3** required by the bot.